# update an existing excel file with outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to learn VBA on my own and i was trying to take the body of an email, parse it out and save only an element of the array into an excel file. I have it doing just that, my issue is that I can't seem to get it updating what's already in the file. It just rewrites with the new email information and saves over it. 
My question to you is: what does my code need to be able to continue writing to my excel file without getting rid of what's already in there.

```
Sub FMK(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Const PathName = "C:\Users\carter\Desktop\fmk.xlsx"

Dim arrLines As Variant, _
varLines As Variant, _
RowNext As Integer, _
xlApp As Excel.Application, _
ExcelWkBk As Excel.Workbook, _
excWkb As Object, _
excWks As Object, _
temp As String

arrLines = Split(Item.Body, vbCrLf)

Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
temp = Trim(arrLines(32))

RowNext = 1
With excWks
    excWks.Cells(RowNext, 1) = temp
End With
RowNext = RowNext + 1

excWkb.SaveAs PathName
excWkb.Close

'this is just for testing purposes  I will remove later 
MsgBox (arrLines(32))
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You are "saving as" i.e. overwriting your existing file if it exists. If you want to add something to an existing file you must open it first.

Comment: oh. okay, let me try that. thank you!

Comment: instead of `set excWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()`, try `set excWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.open(pathName)`. You're currently creating a new workbook rather than open the existing one. You'll need to update your destination sheet to, most likely.

Comment: thanks! that made the .save work. though i'm still not sure how to make it write to the next available row. for example if the workbook already has
cat
dog
and i get a new email with frog, i want it to just add it
cat
dog 
frog
Instead it just writes frog and gets rid of cat and dog.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the last used row and put your new data after it. Something like:-

```
RowNext = excWks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
with excWks
...
```

(and you probably want to Dim RowNext as Long rather than Integer)

xlCellTypeLastCell can be unreliable because it is only reset when the file is saved - maybe that will be good enough for your needs. if not, then see [OzGrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm) for some other suggestions.